# How to add Hovering Annotation for the Y value of a Horizontal Line in Plotly created using figure.add_shape(type='line')

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization, plotly-python

**TL;DR**: How to add Hovering Annotation which displays `5` for the code below:

```
fig.add_shape(type="line", x0=1, x1=2, y0=5, y1=5,line_width=1.5, line_dash="dot", line_color="red")
```

I have this code for displaying Candlesticks plotting Pivot lines on them based on the data. IT works completely fine. I just want to show the `y` value when you take the cursor to the Horizontal line to get the exact value. Below is the part of code I'm using to display Horizontal Pivot, Support Resistance and Vertical Day Break Lines:

```
# I already have a Figure Object from plotly which I access

fig = go.Figure(data = [go.Candlestick(opacity = 0.9, x = stocks[Date], name = 'X',
                                                  open = stocks[Open], high = stocks[High], low = stocks[Low], close = stocks[Close]),])
fig.add_shape(type="line", x0=1, x1=2, y0=5, y1=5,line_width=1.5, line_dash="dot", line_color="red")
```

How can I add Hovering Value info to these?

Here is my actual chart and all the `Horizontal` lines have been plotted using `fig.add_shape(type='line')`

[image]

Comment: without a MWE showing data and creation of figure difficult to provide a solution.  the way I would expect to solve this is to replace layout shapes with additional traces for the lines.  clearly traces do have hover capability

Comment: Example would be too big to paste here so you can perfectly assume MWE as the first line of code. I just want to see if I can see `5` on the first line. IF you have any other idea on how to draw `limited` Horizontal lines differently, please paste that approach too.

Comment: so you want me to write code to create the figure to then run that line of code against to make a MWE?  ok ... I'll make all the assumption I want so may not meet what you are doing at all ...

Comment: Please check the update. I am doing everything on `fig = go.Figure(data = [go.Candlestick(opacity = 0.9, x = stocks[Date], name = 'X',
                                                  open = stocks[Open], high = stocks[High], low = stocks[Low], close = stocks[Close]),])`

Comment: does your data start in 1970, i.e. the epoch? `x0=1` implies it does

Comment: No, it'll be filled dynamically based on a variable. No issues about that. If I can know how to show the `5` in this EXACT data, I'll do it for my code. you can assume `x0=pd.to_datetime('13-01-2022'), x1=pd.to_datetime('14-01-2022')` or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- it's straight forward to replace layout shapes with traces
- this shows this within the bounds of your sample code, where I had to imply your data started at epoch and your line would be for only 4 milliseconds, so I extended it to 4.5 hrs

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np

# setup all necessary variables and MWE could not be provide :-(
stocks = pd.read_csv(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv",
    parse_dates=["Date"],
)
$ rebase data to start at epoch as sample code implies it does
stocks["Date"] = pd.date_range("1-jan-1970", freq="1Min", periods=len(stocks))
Date = "Date"
Open = "AAPL.Open"
High = "AAPL.High"
Low = "AAPL.Low"
Close = "AAPL.Close"


fig = go.Figure(
    data=[
        go.Candlestick(
            opacity=0.9,
            x=stocks[Date],
            name="X",
            open=stocks[Open],
            high=stocks[High],
            low=stocks[Low],
            close=stocks[Close],
        ),
    ]
)


# replace this line of code.  but it's implications are weird.  line for 4 milliseconds just after epoch
# fig.add_shape(type="line", x0=1, x1=2, y0=5, y1=5,line_width=1.5, line_dash="dot", line_color="red")
# replace with this - let's make it 4.5hrs long
fig.add_shape(
    type="line",
    x0=1,
    x1=1.5 * 10 ** 7,
    y0=5,
    y1=5,
    line_width=1.5,
    line_dash="dot",
    line_color="red",
)
# equivalend as a trace, and now have hover...
fig.add_traces(
    go.Scatter(
        x=np.linspace(1, 1.5 * 10 ** 7, 100),
        y=np.repeat([5], 100),
        mode="lines",
        line_dash="dot",
        line_color="red",
        showlegend=False,
    )
)
```

[image]